# How do I rename the git directory back to .git in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, directory

To save away the `.git` directory, I temporarily renamed it to `.git.saved` on Windows 2008. But now I can't rename it back to `.git`! Windows explorer would not let me to rename anything to `.xxx`. I also tried command prompt with rename and move commands. Both commands failed with `The system cannot find the file specified` error. But if I do the command `dir .git.saved`, it displays the `.git.saved` contents. So how can I get `.git` back?

Comment: See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows#).

Comment: Never mind, I got an answer. The original .git directory had "hidden" flag checked. So command prompt commands do not see it. After uncheck the "hidden" flag from the properties, the command prompt commands now sees it and I could rename it back to .git again.